# MouseEvents in JFrame seem extremely unpredictable

Tags: java, swing, jframe, mouseevent

I'm trying to code a level creator for my game in which you drag objects to their desired positions, but I'm having trouble figuring out whether or not the mouse button is being held down.

I'm using a `MouseAdapter` to listen for `mouseClicked` and `mouseReleased` events, but they seem to fire unpredictably. Usually, the program doesn't register either the mouse being clicked or released, but on occasion, one will be fired when it shouldn't be. A SOE will be thrown here and there, and eventually, they will be thrown repeatedly until the program is terminated. Any suggestions on working around this?

Comment: Post your code here as an SSCCE (see http://sscce.org/), and the stack traces of any exceptions (in your case, `StackOverflowError`s).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're probably listening for the wrong events.  `MOUSE_CLICKED` means `MOUSE_PRESSED` + `MOUSE_RELEASED`.

I think you probably want to be looking for `MOUSE_PRESSED` instead of clicked.

See the api for `MouseEvent` for more details:  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseEvent.html

Also, the `MOUSE_DRAGGED` event may be of some use to you.

Comment: Thanks, that's quite helpful.